# ERROR!:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have read many other questions regarding this error, but it doesn't solve mine, that's the reason i made this question despite the obvious thought that many have been asking this before me.

This is my connect.php

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';


try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Login', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row){
        print_r($row);
    }

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e){
    print "ERROR!:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();

}
```

But I am having trouble, I am certain that the $user and $pass is correct, but I still keep getting this message, I am new to PDO - can this have anything to do with it?

When I load this on my localhost I get the error message:

> ERROR!:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

To me it seems like this error message is telling me either that the `$pass = 'NO'` which it doesn't or that the $pass is wrong? I tried to change the `$pass = 'NO';` and got the following error:

> ERROR!:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Then - playing stupid here I change `$pass = 'YES'`;
got me this error:

> ERROR!:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You have to add the correct root password to `$pass`

Comment: If you have given correct username and password then check with user privileges for the database you used.

Comment: The `using password` phrase does not echo _what_ password you are using, just whether or not you are using one. You have the wrong password for your root account.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `wamp`, this might be a possible solution.

-> Change `localhost`  to `127.0.0.1`.
So it becomes

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';


try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Login', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row){
        print_r($row);
    }

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e){
    print "ERROR!:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();

}
```

Also, just put all the connection code in a different file, say "dbconnector.php". Include it in everypage wherever you need to use your DB. Now you can have the connection accessible via the `$dbh` variable.

Comment: thanks for quick and nice replies, i have now changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1 - i am on a mac using mamp, but now it throws me another error: "ERROR!:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused". Which makes me think that it might be because - as comments also mentioned. that even tough i believe with 99% certain that the $pass = ''; must be something else? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Anders 
I'm really not sure about things work on a mac. But mostly mysql password for every wamp installation on windows is `empty`.
Try to upload to a server and test it?